# How to create the most flexible abstraction of FormDialog with react-hook-form and MUI Dialog?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

In my react app, I have been having to write quite a lot of code for displaying the form with dialog and I thought it would be nice to absctract away some common functions. Every form dialog will have this functionality in common :

1. Call `useForm` and handle form submission
2. When the dialog is closed and if the form is dirty, I want to ask users for
   confirmation

I have been trying to do that for the entire day and keep hitting problems. Here is how the components would look like

`Dialog`

We already have the `Dialog` component in our codebase that is re-usable and inside the `Dialog`, we can display the children, like this

`Dialog Component`

```
<CustomDialog
 onClose={closeDialog}
 triggerButton={<Button>Display Form With Dialog</Button>}
>
  <FormComponent />
</CustomDialog>
```

`Form Component`

```
const {register,handleSubmit} = useForm()

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <TextField {...register('username')} />
   ....
</form>
```

As you can see, closing the `Dialog` happens inside `DialogComponent` and the state to check whether the form is dirty or not is inside the `FormComponent` itself. I can't lift the `formMethods` up the parent component because, that will cause the issues of the `formStates` being persistent. Right now, the `FormComponent` is only mounted when the `Dialog` is opened. If I were to lift the `formMethods` up, they will be persistent.

I don't want to use `useImperativehandle` to let the `Dialog` know the `formState/isDirty` either. Because, that will be too much repetetive and I want more reusable code.

Do you guys have any good solutions?